# No positive integers $(a,b)$ satisfying $2^b -1\mid 2^a +1$ (AoPS Vol 2)

Tags: elementary-number-theory, solution-verification, well-orders, infinite-descent

I posted this proof on AoPS but I'm having trouble understanding what's wrong with it. I was hoping this community could offer a different perspective?

> Suppose the claim is false. That is to say, suppose there exists an integer pair $(a,b)$ such that $2^b-1$ evenly divides $2^a+1$. For a given $b_0>2$ there exists a non-empty set of positive integers $S=\left\{a_0,\ldots,a_n\right\}$ that are counterexamples to the claim (we let $b_0>2$ because $(a,1)$ and $(3,2)$ are counterexamples). Let $a_0$ be the smallest value of $S$. Then
> $$\frac{2^{a_0} +1}{2^{b_0}-1}=k$$for some $k\in \mathbb{Z}$. Therefore,
> $$\frac{2^{a_0}+1+2^{b_0}-1}{2^{b_0}-1}=k+1$$Hence,
> $$\frac{2^{a_0}+2^{b_0}}{2^{b_0}-1}=k+1$$So,
> $$\frac{2^{b_0}(2^{a_0-b_0}+1)}{2^{b_0}-1}=k+1$$Because $2^{b_0}-1\nmid 2^{b_0}$, we find that $2^{b_0}-1\mid 2^{a_0-b_0}+1$, so $a_0-b_0\in S$. However, $a_0-b_0<a_0,$ contradicting the minimality of $a_0$. Therefore, $S$ is empty. $\blacksquare$

Comment: Well... where did you use the assumption that $b_0>2$?

Comment: the example a=3, b=2   does not belong in the body; it should be at the beginning and the hypotheses should include $ a \geq 4, b \geq 3$  For a "descent" argument, one must identify the method of descent, but one must, very carefully, describe precisely what is going on in the bottom of the descent.

Comment: $(2n+1,2),\;n\in\mathbb{N}$ are counterexamples, too.

Comment: As a (minor) technical point:  It is not generally true that $m\,|\,ab$ and $m\,\nmid a$ implies that $m\,|\,b$.  For example, $4$ divides $2\times 2$ but $4$ does not divide either factor.  What (I think) you meant to write was that $\gcd\left(2^{b_0}-1,2^{b_0}\right)=1$.  That's enough to move the argument along.

Comment: Is the proof intended to be "For all $b > 2$," since those specific counterexamples are called out? If so, that should be right in the initial statement. Also, I'm uncertain this is technically proof by infinite descent; isn't this just a simple proof by contradiction? There's no requirement that one would further need smaller and smaller $a_1, a_2, \cdots$. With the corrections made by other commenters, though, the remainder seems fine.

Comment: @lulu That’s what i had in my head, i just didn’t articulate it right. i’ll change it. thank you!